# Is "updates done" grammatically correct?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, headlinese

Is "updates done" grammatically correct. I am trying to use an alternative for "changes made"

> List of changes made -

or

> List of updates done -

or is there anything else I can use?

Comment: _"Updates done"_ is commonly used as a synonym for _"Changes made"_.  But it depends on your context. Sometimes they cannot be interchanged. There's nothing wrong with _"Updates done"_.

Comment: *update* is a noun. It *can* be done! So, why not? [*Event is not the first Facebook update done for mobile first...*](http://www.ibtimes.com/facebook-events-update-android-users-get-cover-art-make-those-special-occasions-pop-2057024). However, I'd prefer this style: ***Changes: done***; ***Updates: done***

Comment: **List of successful updates** could be used. Sounds like it your usage is technology related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-cast these phrases to full sentences, and then ask yourself the question:

> List of changes he/I/we made:
>
> List of changes he/I/we done:
>
> Updates he/I/we made:
>
> Updates he/I/we done:

Yes, "updates done" is common, but not - to answer your specific question - grammatically correct.